# eSATA device labelled wrongly

Tags: ssd, external-hard-drive, device-manager, esata

I have a [MSI P45 Platinum](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/P45_Platinum__P45_Zilent.html#hero-overview) motherboard which has a JMB362-powered eSATA port. I recently bought a Samsung 850 EVO 250GB SSD which I inserted into a [StarTech eSATA + USB 3.0 enclosure](https://www.startech.com/HDD/Enclosures/esatap-usb-3-sata-6gbps-hdd-enclosure~S251SMU33EP), and plugged it into the eSATA port. It recognised the device as a "WDC WD10EARS-00Y5B1 SCSI Disk Device"! [image: Erroneous Naming of eSATA drive]

One possible reason for this is that the previous device I had plugged in into this port was a HDD of that model inside a Transcend Storejet 35 eSATA + USB 2.0 enclosure.

How do I fix this misnaming?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the software.

Comment: @Ramhound: Which software? The JMicron driver? Windows?

Comment: CrystalDiskInfo

Comment: @Ramhound No, the disk in the enclosure was actually Samsung 850 EVO 250GB.